# Struts OGNL expression

Tags: struts2, ognl

I have 2 struts hidden tags as follows:-
`<s:hidden name="userList" id="userList"></s:hidden>`
`<s:hidden name="userId" id="tUserId" value="%{#userData.userId}" />`

userId will have a value like 101.
userList will have a value like 101,102,103

I am facing an issue while trying to evaluate the following expression in struts if tag.

`<s:if test ="%{#userData.userId in {userList}}">`

I've tried a lot of possibilities, read articles, tutorials but didn't find a suitable answer to my problem.

Comment: If I evaluate like this `<s:if test ="%{#userData.userId in {'101','102', '103'}}">` it works, but it doesn't work with the userList. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: Did you try `%{#userData.userId in userList}` or possibly `%{#userData.userId in #userList}`?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes I tried both of those, but didn't work.

Comment: You'll probably need to include information like the types of everything in question in order to reproduce the issue.